# How to solve the apache beam's 'Must return void or ProcessContinuation' error?

Tags: java, apache-beam, void

I am new to apache beam and trying to familiarize with the transforms. I'm building a silly pipeline but just from trying to print the elements of a PCollection (witch I have done before in the same way), I got this error.
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.beam.examples.PasswordChecker$checkPassword, @ProcessElement processElement(ProcessContext): Must return void or ProcessContinuation`
This is my code:

```
package org.apache.beam.examples;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class PasswordChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    List<String> passwords = new ArrayList<>();
    passwords.add("Roger85senhas");
    passwords.add("1132o31231230123");
    passwords.add("MyPassword28");
    passwords.add("1234");
    passwords.add("Carla04082002!");
    passwords.add("miemiemeimmeie");

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
    PCollection<String> pass = p.apply(Create.of(passwords));
    
    PCollection<HashMap<String, Boolean>> validity = pass.apply(ParDo.of(new checkPassword()));

    validity.apply(ParDo.of(new printElements()));

    p.run();
    }

    public static class checkPassword extends DoFn<String, HashMap<String,Boolean>>{
        @ProcessElement
        public KV<String, Boolean> processElement(ProcessContext c){
            String password = c.element();
            if (password.length() > 7 & password.length() < 15){
                return KV.of(password, true);
            }
            return KV.of(password, false);
        }
    }

    public static class printElements extends DoFn<HashMap<String, Boolean>, Void>{
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(HashMap<String, Boolean> c) {
            for (String key : c.keySet()){
                System.out.println(String.format("The %s password is %s", key, c.get(key) ? "valid" : "not valid"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to print the values of the 'validity' PCollection. I didn't compile because of this
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.beam.examples.PasswordChecker$checkPassword, @ProcessElement processElement(ProcessContext): Must return void or ProcessContinuation`
error.

Comment: Can you check https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo for `OutputReceiver`? 

```
static class ComputeWordLengthFn extends DoFn<String, Integer> {
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(@Element String word, OutputReceiver<Integer> out) {
    // Use OutputReceiver.output to emit the output element.
    out.output(word.length());
  }
}
```
More learning resources are here https://beam.apache.org/get-started/. Tour of Beam is very useful to learn basics.